# Led and basic light bulbs; 2 light sockets. One works with both bulbs, the other doesn't.

Tags: led, lighting

I live in an older house and I have a two-socket light fixture in my bedroom. One socket will work with both an LED bulb and a basic (wire??) bulb. The other socket, however, only works with the basic bulb. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Chelsea, you've stumbled into a site for electronics design questions so you'll probably get migrated to DIY or Home Improvements or similar. Edit your question to state country, voltage, part number of LED lamp and whether or not you've got a dimmer switch or something odd. Also clarify that the LED works in a normal lamp fitting. A photo is probably essential.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the light not fit? Or does it fit fine, but not light up? Does one socket have a dimmer and the other doesn't (if this is the case, the light itself might be incompatible with dimmers). Please post a picture so peeps would have a better idea.

Comment: Seconding the request for a picture here, although I suspect the socket that doesn't work with the LED bulb is simply not making proper physical contact with the bulb-base.

Comment: The *"basic (wire?) bulb"* is usually called an *incandescent bulb* though you could also call it a *tungsten filament bulb*.

Answer (score 2):

With the power off, try tugging gently at the pad in the middle of the socket well. You want it to be sprung a little further out. (Needle nose pliers can be useful for this.) There's a strong chance that it is pushed in a little too far to make contact with the tail of the bulb. If you pull it too much and it breaks, get another fixture.